# Selenium Web Driver - How to handle dynamic in href link

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

Below is the HTML:

```
<a href="#report-adhoc/32|227/result">Result</a>
```

I have dynamic value here, keep changing when page refreshes! how to handle this. Please advise.

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#report-adhoc/**32|229**/result']")).click();
```

Comment: Is this the only report on the page? Or you can see multiple elements with similar href but with the dynamic part?

Comment: If you don't present us the page or some html we can't help you. We can't guess what happened in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Though the *value* is dynamic,

- If the *linkText* **Result** is unique within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) you can use the *Link Text* inducing *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

  - `linkText`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Result"))).click();
    ```
- If the *linkText* **Result** is **not** unique within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) you can use the *XPath* inducing *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

  - `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'report-adhoc') and contains(.,'Result')]"))).click();
    ```